# Set the custom attributes of a subclass of a View with custom attributes?

Tags: android, android-layout

If I have the following setup:

```
public class ABCView extends View {
    //implementation here
}
```

With the following custom attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name = "ABCView" >
       <attr name="foo" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

If I want to subclass this View with another one, but still be able to specify the values of custom attributes in XML, how can I do that?

```
public class DEFView extends ABCView {
    //implementation here
}
```

But when I attempt to use the child view in XML, I get an error - it doesn't recognize that the attribute applies, as it doesn't seem to know about the relationship between the java classes. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

**Since XML won't about java class hierarchy, you might want to specify the custom attributes explicitly for the sub-sub-classed view as well.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name = "DEFView" >
       <attr name="foo" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```